# Booting Ubuntu from Ext SSD?

Tags: boot, ssd

I have downloaded Ubuntu (most recen version), and used image burner on .iso file to create another .iso file in my hard drive, but when I try and boot from my hard drive, it wont let me?

Answer (score 0):

Just copying over a .iso file to the external SSD wont work. Your external drive needs to be prepared for booting. By 'prepared' i mean, there are several things which happen behind the scenes to enable the drive to be used as a bootable device. First the contents are copied over to drive and then a bootloder is written to the MBR of the drive. We need not do all these things manually. There are several tools available to accomplish this task. For ex: [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Before using these tools, just ensure to backup the data of your SDD as it might get erased.